# Difference in hex output from crypto and other encryption libraries?

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I really could use some explanation on this one. Im using crypto to encrypt something in hex. The hex output is different from what Ruby would give me for the same algorithm (sha-256-ecb).

Example from ruby: `\x15\x16\x02F\xD8\xFFwE\x91 (...)`

Example from node: `e67b2c88dd0cedeb29f2e02df98d48eb2f2e3470bf99b (...)`

What's the difference in these formats?

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's `.digest` method returns a binary encoded string represented in hex form.
If you used the `.hexdigest` method in ruby to get a hex encoded string instead, you'd get the same results as in NodeJS:

Ruby:

```
require 'digest';
sha256 = Digest::SHA256.new
sha256.hexdigest 'message'
// "ab530a13e45914982b79f9b7e3fba994cfd1f3fb22f71cea1afbf02b460c6d1d"
```

NodeJS:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
hash.update('message');
hash.digest('hex');
// "ab530a13e45914982b79f9b7e3fba994cfd1f3fb22f71cea1afbf02b460c6d1d"
```

NodeJS is capable of encoding as binary too:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
hash.update('message');
hash.digest('binary');
// Buffer returned
```

But I am not aware of a simple, native solution to convert the buffer to a Ruby-style `\xXXXX` hex representation